# How do I get the inner join and sub-sql correct?

Tags: sql, join, group-by

Here is the question:

Which nine counties sell the highest number of bottles of liquor per capita (per person)? Calculate the average bottle size of the bottles of liquor sold by these counties rounded to the nearest first decimal place. Of the nine counties selling the highest number of bottles of liquor per capita, which county sells (on average) the largest bottle size?

Here are the tables:
[image]

Here are the codes I have so far:

```
sql = """
Select s.county, (s.bottle_qty/c.population) As sale_per_cap, lar_bott_sz = (Select p.bottle_size
                   From products As p
                   Where s.item = p.item_no)
From sales As s, counties As c
Inner Join counties On c.county = s.county
Group By c.county
Order By sale_per_cap
Limit 10
"""
```

I am so new to SQL. Please help me with this.
Many thanks!!!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want joins and aggregation:

```
select 
    c.county,
    sum(s.bottle_quantity) / c.population bottles_per_person,
    avg(p.bottle_size) avg_bottle_size
from counties c
inner join sales s on s.county = c.county
inner join products p on p.item_no = s.item
group by c.county, c.population
order by bottles_per_person desc
limit 9
```

The query joins tables `counties`, `sales` and `products`, and then aggregate by `county`. The bottles per person ratio is computed by dividing the sum of sales `bottle_quantity` by the population of the county; we use it to order the results an limit the number of results.